# How to take decision in a state-machine

Tags: python, transition, state-machine

I'm building a state-machine based on [transitions](https://github.com/pytransitions/transitions) but probably a generic state-machine question. I'm struggling to build a simple decision tree.

The simplified state-machine should look like

```
[state:new] --- generateXYZ ---> [state:generation_successful]
                            ---> [state:generation_failed]
```

I understand that I could create two transitions and guard them but that doesn't feel like the ideal solution - maybe you correct me on that one.

Ideally I'd like to run some code and it's either returning true (=successful) or false(=failed).

Looking forward to any advice, maybe I'm looking at this from the wrong angle. Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by making a decision?

Comment: You could add an `on_enter()` which runs the `generateXYZ()` which includes generating the trigger for the relevant transition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to Stack Overflow!

> build a simple decision tree.

I assume you are not interested in a `generating` state. If generation could take a while, adding such a state might be useful to adjust the model/machine behaviour in case it is 'busy'.

> I understand that I could create two transitions and guard them

I'd guess eventually two different destinations have to result in two transitions. However, with `transitions` you can make use of `conditions` in transition definitions and also wrap your transition creation for more convenience. I use `GraphMachine` to illustrate the result:

```py
from transitions.extensions.diagrams import GraphMachine as Machine
import random


class Model:

    def __init__(self):
        self.machine = Machine(self, states=['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'AF', 'BF', 'F'], initial='A', show_conditions=True)
        # decision trees are easier to read top to bottom
        # configure graphviz accordingly 
        self.machine.machine_attributes['rankdir'] = 'TB'
        self._generated = False

    def add_decision(self, trigger, source, execute, check, on_success, on_fail):
        # this transition will be evaluated first, when execute returns true it will be used
        self.machine.add_transition(trigger, source, on_success, prepare=execute, conditions=check)
        # if this transition is evaluated, we know that a) execute has been called and b) it returned False
        # thus, we could omit 'unless'
        self.machine.add_transition(trigger, source, on_fail, unless=check)

    def generate(self):
        self._generated = bool(random.getrandbits(1))  # returns True of False randomly

    def generated(self):
        return self._generated


model = Model()
model.add_decision('execute', 'A', execute='generate', check='generated', on_success='B', on_fail='AF')
model.add_decision('execute', 'B', execute='generate', check='generated', on_success='C', on_fail='BF')
model.add_decision('execute', 'AF', execute='generate', check='generated', on_success='C', on_fail='F')
model.add_decision('execute', 'C', execute='generate', check='generated', on_success='D', on_fail='F')

# call execute twice
model.execute()
model.execute()

# let's see where we ended up
model.get_graph().draw('graph.png', prog='dot')
```

This will result in something like this:

[image: State Machine Graph]

In my case, generation was successful during the first run and failed in the second run. You can condense this code by a) not using `GraphMachine`, b) making `generate` return `False` or `True` and pass it directly to conditions:

```py
# ... Model.add_decision
        self.machine.add_transition(trigger, source, on_success, conditions=execute)
        self.machine.add_transition(trigger, source, on_fail)
# ...
    def generate(self):
        return bool(random.getrandbits(1))  # returns True of False randomly
# ...
model.add_decision('execute', 'A', execute='generate', on_success='B', on_fail='AF')
```

Code and graph comprehensibility might suffer though.

Comment: Big thanks @aleneum, highly appreciated! Your example cleared things up for me and I'll try to go down this route:
`self.machine.add_transition(trigger, source, on_success, conditions=execute)` and
`self.machine.add_transition(trigger, source, on_fail)`